# SQL Left Join - menor data maior do que data actual

Tags: sql, query, data, join

3 tabelas: `Processo`, `Evento`, `Alerta`

O objectivo é fazer uma consulta que devolva todos os processos acrescentando as colunas do tipo de evento e data do evento mais recente `MAX(DataEvento)` e o próximo alerta (menor data maior do que a data actual) e observações do alerta.

```
SELECT p.id
      ,p.scope
      ,p.entrydate
      ,p.applicant
      ,p.status
      ,MAX(ev.eventdatetime) lastevent
      ,ev.type
      ,ev.eventobs
      ,MIN(al.deadlinedate) nextalert
      ,al.alertobs
  FROM process p
  LEFT JOIN event ev
    ON ev.processid = p.id
  LEFT JOIN alert al
    ON al.eventid = ev.eventid
   AND al.expiredate > getdate()
 GROUP BY p.id
         ,p.scope
         ,p.entrydate
         ,p.applicant
         ,p.status
         ,ev.type
         ,ev.eventobs
         ,al.expiredate
         ,al.alertobs
```

O código acima repete todos os processos várias vezes, consoante o número de eventos.

```
    SELECT p.id
      ,p.scope
      ,p.entrydate
      ,p.applicant
      ,p.status
      ,MAX(ev.eventdatetime) lastevent
      ,ev.type
      ,ev.eventobs
      ,MIN(al.deadlinedate) nextalert
      ,al.alertobs
  FROM process p
 INNER JOIN event ev
    ON ev.processid = p.id
 INNER JOIN alert al
    ON al.eventid = ev.eventid
 WHERE ev.processid = p.id
   AND a.expiredate > getdate()
 GROUP BY p.id
         ,p.scope
         ,p.entrydate
         ,p.applicant
         ,p.status
         ,ev.type
         ,ev.eventobs
         ,al.alertobs
```

Lista apenas um processo, aquele que tem o evento mais recente.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
               ,p.scope
               ,p.entrydate
               ,p.applicant
               ,p.status
               ,(SELECT TYPE
                      ,MAX(ev.eventdatetime) lastevent
                      ,eventobs
                  FROM event ev
                 WHERE ev.processid = p.id
                 GROUP BY TYPE
                         ,eventobs)
               ,(SELECT MIN(a.expiredate) nextalert
                      ,alertobs
                  FROM event ev
                 INNER JOIN alert a
                    ON ev.eventid = a.eventid
                 WHERE ev.processid = p.id
                   AND a.expire > getdate())
  FROM process p
 ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

Aqui dá o erro:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

O que pretendo é listar todos os processos cada um aparece uma única vez e são apresentados os campos do query, acrescentando a data, tipo e observações do último evento e a data e observações do próximo alerta, exemplo:

```
1|Registo|21/06/2018|João Sousa|Activo|21/06/2018|Entrada do processo|Observações do evento|26/06/2018|Prazo para resposta

2|Pedido|21/06/2018|Pedro Antunes|Activo|21/06/2018|Entrada do processo|Observações do evento|26/06/2018|Prazo para resposta
```

Comment: passa a estrutura das tabelas por favor

Comment: As tabelas são maiores na verdade, simplifiquei aqui para colocar a questão...

Comment: olha esse: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xzzMqmDGQe6TXFg9LchNqw/0

Comment: Sim, lista correctamente, no entanto trata-se de T-SQL e não tem a questão do alerta. O alerta está associado ao evento e cada evento pode ter 1 ou vários alertas, preciso listar a menor data do alerta maior do que a data actual. Vou tentar adaptar essa solução, creio que estes detalhes causam alguma confusão na sintaxe, quando conseguir coloco aqui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderão ser necessários pequenos ajustes pois ainda não testei se as datas carregadas são sempre as correctas, mas nunca será muito diferente da lista que obtenho com o código abaixo:

```
 SELECT p.id
      ,p.scope
      ,p.entrydate
      ,p.applicant
      ,p.status
      ,ev.type
      ,ev.eventdatetime AS lastevent
      ,ev.eventobs
      ,MIN(al.expiredate) nextalert
      ,al.alertobs
  FROM process p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN event ev
    ON ev.processid = p.id
   AND ev.eventid = (SELECT top(1) eventid
                       FROM event e
                      WHERE e.processid = ev.processid
                      ORDER BY e.eventdatetime DESC)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN alert al
    ON al.processid = p.id
   AND al.alertid =
       (SELECT top(1) alertid
          FROM alert a a.deadlinedate > getdate())
 GROUP BY p.id
         ,p.scope
         ,p.entrydate
         ,p.applicant
         ,p.status
         ,ev.type
         ,ev.eventdatetime
         ,ev.eventobs
         ,al.alertobs
```

Muito obrigado @Rovann Linhalis pela ajuda preciosa.

Comment: certo, normalmente perguntas com query sem as tabelas e sem registros de amostra ficam um tanto confusas... sempre coloque esses dados e se possível monte um SQLFiddle... ajuda muito...; Por nada, sempre que precisa a comunidade ajuda =]

Comment: Sim, vou lembrar disso para a próxima!

Answer (score 2):

Só usar SubSelect:

```
SELECT 
    p.Id, 
    p.Scope, 
    p.EntryDate, 
    p.Applicant, 
    p.Status,
    (SELECT 
         MAX(ev.EventDateTime) 
     FROM event ev 
     WHERE ev.processId = p.id) as evento_recente,
    (SELECT 
         MIN(a.ExpireDate) 
     FROM event ev 
     INNER JOIN Alert a ON ev.eventid = a.eventId 
     WHERE ev.processId = p.id) as proximo_alerta
FROM Process p
```

Comment: Perfeito, só faltou comparar a data com a data actual nesta linha: (Select MIN(a.ExpireDate) from event ev inner join Alert a on ev.eventid = a.eventId where ev.processId = p.Id and a.ExpireDate > GETDATE()) as proximo_alerta. Obrigado

Comment: Quando tento carregar outras colunas do evento ou do alerta seleccionados dá o seguinte erro: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. Como posso ultrapassar isso?

Comment: tem que ver sua query, parece erro de sintaxe

Comment: Com left join consigo reunir todas as colunas que pretendo, no entanto, repete o mesmo processo para cada evento em vez de mostrar apenas o último. Modificando o subquery que sugeriu antes para incluir as restantes colunas que pretendo dá o erro que referi. A lógica parece estar correcta, provavelmente é um problema de sintaxe sim, mas estou com dificuldade em resolver apesar de já ter consultado vários exemplos aparentemente semelhantes

Comment: @OMB edite sua pergunta, coloque como está sua query agora e um exemplo dos dados que estão retornando, e um exemplo de como deveriam retornar

Comment: Editado. A solução do subquery que sugeriu antes serve perfeitamente desde que consiga adicionar também o tipo e observações do evento e as observações do alerta, mas não estou a acertar com a sintaxe para o fazer.

Comment: @OMB vc não colocou um exemplo de como os dados estão... mas acho que é só usar o `Distinct` : `SELECT DISTINCT
    p.Id,` ...

Comment: Supondo que há n eventos no processo 1, esse processo é listado n vezes, uma para cada evento. Já tentei usar o Distict, não funciona...

Comment: veja se é o mesmo problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/308450/69359

Comment: Exacto, o mesmo problema, vou ver se alguma solução serve para mim