# Query SQL, Mostrar sempre primeiro registro de um campo que se repete

Tags: sql, query

Estou com dificuldade de listar somente uma linha de cada processo.
A query precisa trazer sempre os protocolos com a ultima revisao.

**Ex: Mostrar somente o processo de numero 2 da ultima revisão 2** 
**e   Mostrar somente o processo de numero 1 da ultima revisão 3**

```
Select 
Numero_Processo Processo
, Numero_Revisao Revisao
,Titulo
,Id
,Data_Criacao
 FROM Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo 
 WHERE Data_Exclusao is null

order by Numero_Processo desc, Numero_Revisao desc
```

Ja tentei o Group By, mas como o campo revisao é sempre é diferente ele traz todos os protocolos com todas as revisões

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem várias maneiras> usar row_number aggregando pela coluna que você quiser ou um self-join ou mesmo uma subqueri p/ retornar o max segundo algum critério e dai retornar só os registros que satisfaçam a sub-query. Favor ao postar uma pergunta sobre query taggear com o SGBD pois vários recursos não são SQL Ansi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui usando select MAX dentro do where

```
SELECT Numero_Processo, Numero_Revisao Revisao,Titulo ,Id ,Data_Criacao 
                                    FROM Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo Qproc
                                    WHERE Data_Exclusao is null
                                    AND   Numero_Revisao = (select Max(Numero_Revisao) processo
                                                                from Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo
                                                                where Numero_Processo = Qproc.Numero_Processo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar assim:

```
SELECT
   Numero_Processo Processo
   , Numero_Revisao Revisao
   , Titulo
   , Id
   , Data_Criacao
FROM 
   Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo
WHERE
   Id = ( 
      SELECT 
         aux.id 
      FROM
         Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo aux 
      WHERE
         aux.Numero_Revisao DESC LIMIT 1 
   ) 
   AND Data_Exclusao IS NULL
ORDER BY 
   Numero_Processo DESC
   , Numero_Revisao DESC
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele continua listando todos os processos pois a Numero_Revisao é diferente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode filtrar pela `Id` com um `sub-select` ordenando pelo número da revisão:

```
SELECT 
    p.processo,
    p.revisao,
    p.titulo,
    p.id,
    p.data_criacao
FROM 
    processos p
WHERE 
   p.id = (
      SELECT top 1 x.id 
      FROM processos x 
      WHERE x.processo = p.processo 
      ORDER BY revisao DESC
   );
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26276/5)